# Struts 1.x tags usage question

Tags: struts, taglib

I have a jsp page with the tags:

```
 <logic:iterate id="var" ...
    ....
    <bean:write name="var" property="p1" ...

    etc.
```

And I need, on each iteration, to generate a href composed from the various bean's properties. I even need to URLEncode some of them so the link works.

Something like

```
 <logic:iterate id="var" ...
    ....
    <html:link action="otheraction.do?_X_

    <bean:write name="var" property="p1" ...

    etc
```

where *X* is generated by collecting the bean's properties; something like

```
 String X="p1="+URLEncode(p1)+"&p2="+SimpleDateFormatof(p2)+"&p3="+p3;
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like I'll be using the old jsp way ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to make one POJO class.
1. Assign all your values to the object in Action which is being called before your jsp page comes in the picture.
2. Keep the object of POJO to request attribute.
3. Get the value from request attribtue on JSP using `<bean:write>` tag.